# Setting width and height

Tags: html, css, chart.js

I'm trying out the example code for Chart.js [given in the docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-creating-a-chart).

Width and height is specified inline on the canvas element at 400px/400px.

But when rendering the chart it's blown up to full page width, and cuts off the far right end.

How/where am I supposed to control the width/height of the chart?

Comment: Don't circumvent the rules to post a link to a CodePen; follow what the rules say and include a [mcve] instead.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You can override the canvas style width !important ...

```
canvas{

  width:1000px !important;
  height:600px !important;

}
```

also

specify `responsive:true,` property under options..

```
options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

update under options added : `maintainAspectRatio: false,`

link : http://codepen.io/theConstructor/pen/KMpqvo

Comment: Thank you, your `maintainAspectRatio: false` made the chart viewable. But still cutting off the right side though. Hitting these kind of issues already with their own basic example code makes me wonder wether chart.js is a good bet. (The right side is still cut off...)

Comment: That solves the problem of graph size, the graph hasn't scaled to fit it. Is there a way to set the graph size from within Chart.js?

Comment: Turns out that you need to turn off responsive to make the graph obey the sizes given to it. Shame that there doesn't seem to way to control it and maintain the responsive nature...

Comment: Using "!important" is not the right way of solving this even though it works. @Nicolas solution below "wrapping the canvas in a div" is a better way as we would have control over resizing the canvas in a way we want it to be.

Comment: +1 to the above. Don't use this method. It doesn't look right if you force the canvas size like this. Use @Nicolas's solution below.

Comment: `canvas{ width:100% !important; height:600px !important; }` and `maintainAspectRatio: false,` solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 102):

You can also simply surround the chart with container (according to official doc http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html#important-note)

HTML

```html
<div class="chart-container">
   <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.chart-container {
   width: 1000px;
   height:600px
}
```

And with options

```js
responsive: true
maintainAspectRatio: false
```

Comment: This works. The key here is to use an outer div and set the width and height on that rather than the canvas element.

Comment: In order for this to work, chart-container should be relatively positioned.

Comment: works for me but only with `!important` in Angular project

Answer (score 36):

In my case, passing `responsive: false` under options solved the problem. I'm not sure why everybody is telling you to do the opposite, especially since true is the default.

Comment: Same here. Setting `responsive: true` completely skewed the appearance of the chart.

Comment: works for me but only with `!important` in my Angular project

Answer (score 17):

I cannot believe nobody talked about using a relative parent element.

Code:

```
<div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:40vh; width:80vw">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Sources: [Official documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html#important-note)

Comment: Its worth noting too, that for some reason the `width` AND `height` need to be set, you cannot simply set `height` as I was trying to do.

Comment: This seems to be the only solution that doesn't compromise the responsiveness of the chart. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can change the `aspectRatio` according to your needs:

```json
options:{
     aspectRatio:4 //(width/height)
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify how this works? `4` is not an aspect ratio. Your comment says `(width/height)` but it's unclear how that should be applied. Is there a way of passing that as a set? Or do you literally mean to divide the proposed width by the proposed height, such that e.g., 3:4 becomes `0.75`?

Comment: works but don't no how. Solved my issue by the way.

Answer (score 1):

This helped in my case:

```
options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            ticks: {
                min:0,
                max:100
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not mentioned above but using `max-width` or `max-height` on the canvas element is also a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me - but dont forget to put this in the "options" param.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: data,
options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive:true,
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this, it works fine.

```
<canvas id="totalschart" style="height:400px;width: content-box;"></canvas>
```

and under `options`,

```
responsive:true,
```

Answer (score -2):

You can create a div to wrap the canvas tag,

```
    <div class="wrap">
     <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>

    .grafico{
      width: 400px !important;
    }
```

any changes in js chart options

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar', //doughnut, bar, line, radar, pie, polarArea
    data: data,
    options: {

      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepSize: 1
        }

      }
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: Howis your answer different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49039089/6367213)?